# Why I can't view the plot after running this matlab code?

Tags: matlab

```
fprintf('Plotting Data ...\n')
data = load('ex1data1.txt');
x = data(:, 1); y = data(:, 2);
m = length(y); % number of training examples

% Plot Data
% Note: You have to complete the code in plotData.m
plotData(x, y);
fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;
```

Here is the matlab code for function plotData:

```
function plotData(x, y)
  plotData (x,y,'rx', 'MarkerSize', 10);
  ylabel ('Profit in $10,000s');
  xlabel('Population of city in 10,000');
  figure;
end
```

After running the above code it gives me the following error:

> Error in plotData (line 16) plotData (x,y,'rx', 'MarkerSize', 10);
>
> Error in ex1 (line 49) plotData(x, y);

Comment: You need to use `plot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function `plotData` inside the function `plotData`, which does not make sense here.

What you want is to call `plot` as follows:

```
plot(x,y,'rx', 'MarkerSize', 10);
```

inside the function.

Therefore change `plotData` to this:

```
function plotData(x, y)

figure %// Note that figure is called before the plot
plot(x,y,'rx', 'MarkerSize', 10);
ylabel ('Profit in $10,000s');
xlabel('Population of city in 10,000');

end
```

Note that I added the call to `figure` before actually generating the plot, which makes more sense to me.

Comment: Sir, should I use plot or plotData in the main code body that I have mentioned in the first block of my code. I have corrected the error that you told me but it still shows me the same error.

Comment: In the 1st block you can use `plotData` in order to call the function. Can you show the whole error message?

Comment: The code is working fine now. Thanks Sir. But I wanna know what the line of code plot() does in my code. I know we have defined the function plotData (x,y) at first, but then what we do in the line of code containing  plot ()

Comment: Great you are welcome. The line displays the data contained in the variables `x` and `y` with a color and line style specified by you. Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?refresh=true) for more details. In your case, you are telling Matlab to plot red crosses as symbols (i.e. `rx`) and with a size of 10.